# multiprocessing - run not called

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I want to call several processes that execute code in a while(true) loop in parallel. The processes shall be closed by pressing x on the keyboard.

```
import sys
import multiprocessing
import random

class Observer(multiprocessing.Process):    
    def __init__(self, obs):
        #super(Observer, self).__init__()
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.terminate = False
        self.obs = obs
        print(obs[0], obs[1])
        sys.stdout.flush()

    def run(self):
        print("In task " + obs)
        sys.stdout.flush()        

        sum = 0
        for i in range(10000):
            sum = sum + random.random()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    observe = [(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4)]

    processes = []
    for obs in observe:
        process = Observer(obs)
        processes.append(process)

    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    print("Started")

    while True:
        answer = input("Terminate program by pressing 'x': ")
        if answer == "x":
            for p in processes:
                p.terminate = True
            break

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    print("Terminated")
```

The output is

> 1 1 
>   1 2
>   1 3
>   1 4
>   Started
>
> Terminate program by pressing 'x': x 
>   Terminated

So the run method of the multiprocessing.Process doesn't seem to be executed (None of the print statements is executed!) Why isn't it? I also tried not overriding the multiprocessing.Process but to use the constructor to build new processes. However, this isn't working neither and I don't understand why...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: can not reproduce, and there is typo in your code.

Comment: It seems that python behaves differently if executed in the IPhyton console. If executed manually from the command line, the code runs just fine...

Comment: ya, IMO don't mess multiprocessing with ipython.